# Dynamic programing parallelisation/vectorization with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, dynamic-programming

Im trying to write a function that computes minimum cost polygon triangulation using dynamic programing and parallize/vectorize it using OpenMP. The code I wrote so far, returns correct results but it is too slow - for polygons that are formed by more than 3000 points it does not even stops after 5 minutes. Here is the code:

```
#pragma omp declare simd
float dist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    return sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2));
}

float triangulate(const vector<Point> &points) {

int n = points.size();

vector<vector<float>> table (n, vector<float>(n, 0));

int threads = omp_get_max_threads();

for (int gap = 0; gap < n; ++gap)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = gap; j < n; ++i, ++j)
    {
        if (j < i+2)
            table[i][j] = 0.0;
        else
        {
            int size = j - i - 1;

            Point p1 = points[i], p2 = points[j];
            //Precompute distance between i and j
            float ij = dist(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            float minimum = MAX;
            #pragma omp parallel for simd schedule(static, 64) num_threads(threads) reduction(min:minimum) if(size > 300)
            for (int k = i+1; k < j; ++k)
            {
                Point p3 = points[k];

                float perimeter = ij + dist(p1.x, p1.y, p3.x, p3.y) + dist(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y) + table[i][k] + table[k][j];

                if(perimeter < minimum)
                {
                    minimum = perimeter;
                }
            }

            table[i][j] = minimum;
        }
    }
}

return table[0][n-1];
}
```

The gap and i,j for loops imho cannot be parallelized so only the for loop over k is possible to parallelize. I tried to play along with schedule arguments, but with no improvement. Am I missing something or just this function cannot be faster within this approach?

Comment: What does a profile tell you?

Comment: Does your compiler do anything useful with the combination parallel for simd reduction if() on strided vectors? Even if it does, moving the parallel to an outer loop has to better when your if threshold needs to be as low as that.   Is the compiler one which requires C++ min() as well as stride 1 for simd optimized code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not parallelize on `i`/`j`?
For a given i/j pair, computing the perimeter only relies on values of `table[i][k]` and `table[k][j]` where the gap between `i` and `k` or between `k`and `j` is smaller than between `i` and `j`. As long as the outermost loop on `gap` is done in order, the inner loop on `i`/`j` has *embarrassing parallelism* properties and can be parallelized without any precaution.

```
// Do this here so that we can dispose of the if/then/else in the loop later
table[0][0] = 0.0;
for (int i= 1; i < n; ++i){
    table[i][i-1] = 0.0;
    table[i][i]   = 0.0;
}

// spawn parallel threads here
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
for (int gap = 2; gap < n; ++gap)
{
    // Loop on i will now be distributed among threads
    // Not sure that is possible to place two variables in the loop definition
    // so loop on i and compute the corresponding value of j
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n-gap; ++i)
    {
        int j=i+gap; 
        int size = gap - 1;

        Point p1 = points[i], p2 = points[j];
        //Precompute distance between i and j
        float ij = dist(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

        float minimum = MAX;

        // remove of all directives but simd
        #pragma omp simd reduction(min:minimum)
        for (int k = i+1; k < j; ++k)
        {
            Point p3 = points[k];

            float perimeter = ij + dist(p1.x, p1.y, p3.x, p3.y) + dist(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y) + table[i][k] + table[k][j];

            if(perimeter < minimum)
                minimum = perimeter;
        }

        table[i][j] = minimum;
    } // implicit barrier, all threads will wait here for loop completion before moving to next value of gap
} //end of loop, end of parallel region
```

Comment: How could I not think about that?? However you have small mistake in the code - `int j=i-gap;` should be `int j=i+gap;` and also the first for loop that fills part of the table with zeros is unnecessary, because the table was initialized with zeros. Anyway thank you so much, it helped me a lot.